# Consistency of monochromatic uniformization at an inaccessible cardinal

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, infinite-combinatorics

Let $\kappa$ be an inaccessible cardinal, is the following uniformization principle at $\kappa$ consistent (is it consistent with GCH?): there exists a ladder system $\langle A_\alpha\subset \alpha: \alpha<\kappa\rangle$ (each $A_\alpha$ is cofinal in $\alpha$) such that for any $c: \kappa \to 2$, there is $d: \kappa \to 2$ such that $\{\alpha<\kappa: d\restriction A_\alpha \equiv^* c(\alpha)\}$ contains a club.

Comment: What do you mean by $\equiv^*$? Is it mod bounded?

Comment: @MihaHabič yes.

Comment: Does this fail if you use two colors on every ladder?